# Как использовать getline для записи строки? Что я делаю не так?

Tags: c++, строки, битовые-операции, enum

Я предполагаю, что дело в строке, но именно её мне и нужно записать. Со строкой я на "вы", поэтому.. так и получается. Если код выглядит неправильно оформленным, то извините уж: мне в Stack Overflow немного трудно писать код так, что-бы всё правильно вывело.

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <Windows.h>

using namespace std;

enum Mask
{
    UPPER = 128,
    SPACE_BETWEEN_LETTERS = 64,
    NEWLINE = 32,
    NOTHING = 16,
    COLOR_AQUA = 8,
    COLOR_GREEN = 4,
    COLOR_BLUE = 2,
    COLOR_BLACK = 1

};

void uppercase(char str[]) {
char* step = str;
while (*step != '\0') {
    *step = toupper(*step);
    ++step;
}
}

void lowercase(char str[]) {
char* step = str;
while (*step != '\0') {
    *step = tolower(*step);
    ++step;
}
}

void space_between_letters(char *&str)
{
    size_t tmp_size = strlen(str) * 2;
    char *tmp = new char[tmp_size];

    for (size_t i = 0, j = 0; j < tmp_size;)
    {
        if (j % 2 == 0 && str[i] != ' ') {
        tmp[j] = ' ';
    }
    else {
        tmp[j] = str[i];
        ++i;
    }
    ++j;
    }
    tmp[tmp_size - 1] = '\0';
    delete[] str;
    str = tmp;
}

void new_line(char *&str)
{
    str[strlen(str)] = '\n';
}

void nothing()
{
    cout << "\n OMG, nothing happened! (kidding: this cout was activated) 
\n";
}

void main() {
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");
    HANDLE h = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);

    unsigned char settings = 0;
    int size;
    cout << "Введите размер строки: ";
    cin >> size;

    char *str = new char[size] {'\0'};
    strcpy(str, "Some text for test");
    char user_choise;

cout << "Введите саму строку (обязательно поставьте точку, когда строка 
будет завершена): ";
cin.getline(str, size, '.');

system("cls");

cout << "Большие (U) или маленькие (L) буквы? (U/L) \n Ваш выбор: ";
cin >> user_choise;

if (user_choise == 'U')
    settings = Mask::UPPER;
else
    lowercase(str);

system("cls");

cout << "Ставить ли пробелы между буквами? (Y/N) \n Ваш выбор: ";
cin >> user_choise;

if (user_choise == 'Y')
    settings = Mask::SPACE_BETWEEN_LETTERS;

system("cls");

cout << "Ставить ли Enter (\\n) после текста? (Y/N) \n Ваш выбор: ";
cin >> user_choise;

if (user_choise == 'Y')
    settings = Mask::NEWLINE;

system("cls");

cout << "Вызвать ли nothing? (Y/N) \n Ваш выбор: ";
cin >> user_choise;

if (user_choise == 'Y')
    settings = Mask::NOTHING;
system("pause");

system("cls");

cout << "Выберите цвет Вашей строки: \n";
cout << "\t 3) Aqua \n";
cout << "\t 2) Green \n";
cout << "\t 1) Blue \n";
cout << "\t 0) Black \n";
cout << " \n Ваш выбор: ";

cin >> user_choise;

if (user_choise == '3') {
    settings = Mask::COLOR_AQUA;
}

if (user_choise == '2') {
    settings = Mask::COLOR_GREEN;
}

if (user_choise == '1') {
    settings = Mask::COLOR_BLUE;
}

if (user_choise == '0') {
    settings = Mask::COLOR_BLACK;
}

if ((settings & Mask::UPPER) == Mask::UPPER) {
    uppercase(str);
}

if ((settings & Mask::SPACE_BETWEEN_LETTERS) == Mask::SPACE_BETWEEN_LETTERS) {
    space_between_letters(str);
}

if ((settings & Mask::NEWLINE) == Mask::NEWLINE) {
    new_line(str);
}

if ((settings & Mask::NOTHING) == Mask::NOTHING) {
    nothing();
}

if ((settings & Mask::COLOR_AQUA) == Mask::COLOR_AQUA) {
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(h, 3);
}

if ((settings & Mask::COLOR_GREEN) == Mask::COLOR_GREEN) {
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(h, 2);
}

if ((settings & Mask::COLOR_BLUE) == Mask::COLOR_BLUE) {
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(h, 1);
}

if ((settings & Mask::COLOR_BLACK) == Mask::COLOR_BLACK) {
        SetConsoleTextAttribute(h, 0);
    }

    cout << "Строка, которая вышла: " << str << endl;

    delete[] str;
    system("pause");

    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: вы этот код вообще можете скомпилировать?

Comment: ну думаю, что у вас тут какие-то проблемы с `getline`

Comment: Пожалуйста, точнее поясните в чем проблема.

Comment: Такое дело: cin.getline как-то неправильно работает, например, вводя текст и нажимая Enter, ввод продолжается до тех пор, пока размер текста не пересечёт заданный лимит (size). Знаю, что дело в нуль-терминаторе, пробовал ставить в функцию \n вместо \0, но при написании размера массива и нажатии Enter пропускается ввод текста. Что с этим делать - не знаю.

Answer (score 1):

Ну, `string` это совсем не `char[]`! Выберите что-то одно, примерно как

```
#define _CRT_SECURE_NO_WARNINGS
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <conio.h>
#include <string>

using namespace std;

enum Mask
{
    UPPER = 128,
    LOWER = 64,
    SPACE_BETWEEN_LETTERS = 32,
    NEWLINE = 16,
};

void uppercase(string&str)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i)
        str[i] = toupper(str[i]); // позволяет сделать буквы заглавными

    cout << "Upper: " << str << endl;
}

void lowercase(string&str)
{
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i)
        str[i] = tolower(str[i]);
}

void space_between_letters(string&str)
{
    // пробелы между буквами
    string res;
    for(int i = 0; i < str.length(); ++i)
        res = res + str[i] + " ";
    str = res;
}
void newline(string&str) {
    // \n после текста
    str += '\n';
}

int main() {
    setlocale(0, "rus");

    unsigned char settings = 0;
    unsigned char user_choise = 0;

    string str;

    system("cls");

    cout << "Введите строку: ";
    getline(cin, str);


    system("cls");

    cout << "Большие (U) или маленькие (L) буквы? \n Ваш выбор: ";
    cin >> user_choise;

    if (user_choise == 'U')
        settings |= Mask::UPPER;
    else if (user_choise == 'L')
        settings |= Mask::LOWER;

    system("cls");

    cout << "Ставить ли пробелы между буквами? \n Ваш выбор (Y/n): ";
    cin >> user_choise;

    if (user_choise == 'Y')
        settings |= Mask::SPACE_BETWEEN_LETTERS;

    system("cls");

    cout << "Ставить ли Enter (\\n) после текста? \n Ваш выбор: ";
    cin >> user_choise;

    if (user_choise == 'Y')
        settings |= Mask::NEWLINE;

    system("cls");

    if ((settings & Mask::UPPER) == Mask::UPPER) {
        uppercase(str);
    }

    if ((settings & Mask::LOWER) == Mask::LOWER) {
        lowercase(str);
    }

    if ((settings & Mask::SPACE_BETWEEN_LETTERS) == Mask::SPACE_BETWEEN_LETTERS) {
        space_between_letters(str);
    }

    if ((settings & Mask::NEWLINE) == Mask::NEWLINE) {
        newline(str);
    }

    cout << hex << settings << endl;

    cout << str << endl;

    system("pause");
}
```

Только учтите, что с введенными русскими буквами все равно будут проблемы...

Comment: А если поставить setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian"), то проблемы всё равно будут?